# Minerar Texto com o Weka

Tags: modelagem, weka, mineração-de-textos

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um arquivo `.arff` executável para utilizar no weka. Lembro que estou minerando textos. Meu arquivo está apresentando erros e não estou conseguindo gerar resultados.

Segue abaixo pedaço do arquivo:

```
@relation texto
@attribute message string
@attribute classe {Teste.Mineracao}


@data
'A palavra “pedófilo” é um composto recente do
substantivo pais (criança) e do verbo phileo
(amar). Com essa base, são encontrados dois
substantivos em grego antigo: paidophilos e
paidophilès. A pedofilia grega é o amor homossexual
e pedagógico de um homem maduro
por um menino impúbere (Binard & Clouard,
1997).
Hoje, de acordo com os autores citados acima,
a pedofilia seria caracterizada pelo desejo
sexual de um adulto em relação às crianças.
Mas, perguntam eles, de que desejo se trata?
Um pai que abusa de sua filha durante anos
pertence à mesma categoria que um homem
que gosta de acariciar meninos de oito anos?
Dutroux – belga que foi notícia recorrente nos
jornais em 1996, quando os corpos de duas meninas
de oito anos, violentadas e mortas por
inanição, foram encontrados enterrados no jardim
de sua casa – nomeado pela opinião pública
de pedófilo, não seria antes um sádico, um
assassino ou um perverso?
O objetivo deste trabalho é mostrar como o
termo pedofilia é entendido pela Folha de S.
Paulo, o jornal de maior circulação no Brasil
hoje. Para tanto, procuro entender suas características
em oposição a outros termos designativos
da violência sexual contra a criança:
estupro, abuso sexual, pornografia e incesto,
contribuindo, dessa forma, para a discussão
acerca da representação da violência sexual e
de seu agressor.', Teste
```

Comment: Olá Franciele, você poderia postar o log de erro?

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer dividir o texto em subStrings formadas por este [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSZ9jQy1sfE) irá lhe ajudar. [Aqui o link](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) para a documentação da função que divide o texto em vetores de palavras.

[Aqui o link](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29#Sparse%20ARFF%20files) para a formatação padrão do arquivo.

Caso isso não resolva, explique melhor o que quer fazer, e quais os erros.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi, no seu arquivo você tem duas classes declaradas, Teste e Mineração, mas em `@data` você tem apenas `Teste`, falta a classe Mineração! Ou você inclui ou apaga do atributo `classe -> @attribute classe {Teste}`